# Execute code after UIView animations finish?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

What is the best way to execute code after an animation finishes (e.g. remove a view from the superview after fading it out)? I see `setAnimationDidStopSelector:` but am unsure of how to use it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's vey simple. You have to define the method like

```
-(void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {
//do smth
}
```

Then just call

```
[UIView beginAnimations: nil context: nil];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate: self]; //or some other object that has necessary method
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector: @selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];
```

You can post the view, that you want to remove. For this you have to do this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations: nil context: someView];
```

and then add in your callback:

```
   -(void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {
        [(UIView*)context removeFromSuperView];
    }
```

Comment: Is the selector interchangeable?

Comment: I just set the target to be the view, then had the selector be `removeFromSuperView`

Comment: No. From the docs: The selector should be of the form: - (void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context. Your method must take the following arguments:

Comment: So you can change the name of the method, but it has to take the exact parameters, as stated in documentation.

Comment: yes, but you were missing parameters. in some situations it could cause leak.

Answer (score 0):

I did this for a label I wanted to make flip. It starts an animation but then wants to start another after the first completes. For your question, instead of starting another animation you can just release and free anything no longer needed.

```
- (void) doIt {
    CGRect  r = self.bounds;

    // Save some context information for after the animation
    struct contextStruct *c;
    c = (struct contextStruct *) malloc( sizeof(struct contextStruct) );
    c->oldHeight = r.size.height;

    [UILabelThatFlips beginAnimations: @"flipMe" context: c];
    [UILabelThatFlips setAnimationDelegate: self];
    [UILabelThatFlips setAnimationDidStopSelector: @selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];
    [UILabelThatFlips setAnimationDuration: 0.3];
    [UILabelThatFlips setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
    if( animation == UILabelAsButtonAnimationFlip ) {
    r.size.height = 0.0;
    self.bounds = r;
    [UILabelThatFlips commitAnimations];
}

- (void) animationDidStop: (NSString *) animationID finished: (NSNumber *) finished context: (void *) context {
    struct contextStruct *c = context;
    CGRect  r = self.bounds;

    [UILabelThatFlips beginAnimations: @"flipBack" context: NULL];
    [UILabelThatFlips setAnimationDelay: 0.08];
    [UILabelThatFlips setAnimationDuration: 0.3];
    [UILabelThatFlips setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
    r.size.height = c->oldHeight;
    self.bounds = r;
    [UILabelThatFlips commitAnimations];

    // Stop up any memory leaks
    free( context );
}
```